# If a git pull request is still pending, how do I continue working across branches?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch, pull-request

*FYI - I'm a relative amateur with git, having used it for a couple of years but only on a very basic level. This is probably a beginner-level question.*

I'm collaborating on a git repo. I created a topic branch named `foo`, made changes, committed, pushed, and sent a pull request for my other collaborators to review and merge.

The pull request is going to take them some time to review. In the meantime, though, I want to continue to contribute to `master`, but I also want to keep using the changes I've made locally in `foo`. Is there a way to do that?

Likewise, if they make changes to `master` that I want to pull, can I somehow get those changes into `foo` (or otherwise use the latest code from both branches) without polluting that branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can branch off your `foo` branch (let's call the new branch `bar`) and commit on this one. You will be able to rebase this branch when changes occur in `master`. Once `foo` is merged into `master` all your changes will already be in there.